# Pointer Cast Warning Between Two unsigned char * Values

Tags: c, warnings

I am getting this warning, warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast, about the next code and I can not understand why.

```
unsigned char *dataBitmap = [self bitmapFromImage:image];
unsigned char *dataArray[(int)image.size.height][(int)image.size.width * 4];

for (int i = 0; i < image.size.width * image.size.height * 4; i += 4) {

    int aux = (int) i / 4;
    int row = (int)(aux / image.size.width);
    int column = i % ((int)image.size.width * 4);

    // Alpha.
    dataArray[row][column] = dataBitmap[i];
    // Red.
    dataArray[row][column + 1] = dataBitmap[i + 1];
    // Green.
    dataArray[row][column + 2] = dataBitmap[i + 2];
    // Blue.
    dataArray[row][column + 3] = dataBitmap[i + 3];
}
```

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
unsigned char *dataArray[(int)image.size.height][(int)image.size.width * 4];
```

should be

```
unsigned char dataArray[(int)image.size.height][(int)image.size.width * 4];
```

Read the error message, and think! It says that you are somehow making a pointer from an integer (or something similar.) This means that you used a pointer where you should use an integer, or the other way round. Read your code from the start to finish, where you used pointers and integers.

Comment: Thank you Yuji but I have read well the warning message. Sorry about the question, I am coding to things at the same time and I have not saw the pointer in the dataArray statement. Thank you anyway.